# Need to run a php program inside a rails produced page

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I plan to use Spree for a shopping site but at some point need to sign some data with a PHP program provided by a bank. The only alternative I can think of is to link to somePage.php that runs PHP program and come back to Spree. Is there any easier way like a sending to some PHP shell inside Ruby? or changing for the view to have php extension?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I would check for a native Ruby way of signing your data in Ruby. Have a look at Spree documentation first, or at your bank specs (they usually are very bad, take how bankers write contracts, they can't be any good at writing software specs).

As a second alternative, if you have the PHP program you should try and translate it in Ruby.

If that is not an option for you then you can play with [open4](http://rubygems.org/gems/open4) like this:

```
status = Open4::popen4("/path/to/php bank_code.php #{data_to_sign}") do |pid, stdin, stdout, stderr|
  out_msg = stdout.read
  err_msg = stderr.read
  logger.error "out_msg #{out_msg}"
  logger.error "err_msg #{err_msg}"
end
handle_error_case if status.existatus != 0
```

Cheers,